# Titanium backup shortcut/widget to toggle app freeze

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, browser, home-screen-shortcuts, titanium-backup

My CyanogenMod 7.2 stock browser refuses to remember its defaults. I've taken to freezing opera mini, my other browser, with Titanium backup when I want to use stock to avoid all the preferred app prompts.

I'd like a faster, more convenient way to toggle the freeze. Is it possible to create a shortcut or widget on the home screen to perform this action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Titanium Backup itself offers the corresponding Widgets:

1. long-press on a free space on your homescreen
2. select to add a widget
3. select *Titanium Backup*
4. select *Action*
5. select one of

   - deactivate App
   - activate & execute App
   - toggle (de)activate App
6. select the app
7. tap the "create widget" button

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. However, Titanium Backup is not in my list of widgets. Could it be a result of installing TB from an apk rather than from Google Play? The apk is the first thing I installed after a ROM upgrade.

Comment: Not sure. I checked this with my installation and it worked -- and I also installed it from SD card. But since then, there have been multiple updates applied via the ma.. *ahem* playstore. Is your TB "in sync" with the market? If not, TB has a "market doctor" to fix that. Then update to the latest version from there, and check again.

Comment: Market Doctor doesn't show Titanium Backup as linkable. I just updated the app from Google Play though, the widget option is still not available.

Comment: That is strange -- I just did it. But wait: Are you using the free or the pro version? Maybe that's Pro only.

Comment: I have pro as well. The widget option is available now after a complete uninstall and reinstall from Google Play.

Comment: Ah -- great! Glad it worked out for you as well, finally! Hav to keep that "complete re-install" in mind, just in case. Thanks for pointing this out!